# WP_Query most viewed posts, in multiple Post Types, last 30 days, excluding a specific taxonomy term

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, wp-query, date, views

OK so I'm about 90% done, the only part that keeps breaking is when I try to exclude a specific taxonomy term.

Break down:

Sorting: ('v_sort' => 'views') This is being done via the popular WP-Postviews plugin.

Post Types: post, videos, music, albums.

Date: The last 30 days.

**Excluded Taxonomy Term:** Taxonomy = content, Term = indy.

The code of what works thus far.

```
<?php

    // Create a new filtering function that will add our where clause to the query
    function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
        // posts in the last 30 days
        $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')) . "'";
        return $where;
    }

    add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );

    // The Query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
        'posts_per_page' => '5',
        'v_sortby' => 'views', 
        'post_type' => array( 'post', 'music', 'videos', 'albums' ) )
     );
    remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
    // The Loop
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
        $the_query->the_post(); ?>

I'm doing stuff here...

    <?php endwhile;

    /* Restore original Post Data 
     * NB: Because we are using new WP_Query we aren't stomping on the 
     * original $wp_query and it does not need to be reset.
    */
    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

How would I exclude the content taxonomy term indy? I'm a beginner btw.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'posts_per_page' => '5',
    'v_sortby' => 'views', 
    'post_type' => array( 'post', 'music', 'videos', 'albums' ),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'content',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'indy' ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )
    )
));
```

to exclude the `indy` term in the `content` taxonomy.

Comment: Doesn't work, it breaks the query.

Comment: ok, I think I had one extra  `)`, the syntax should be ok now ;-)

Comment: any luck so far?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
<?php

// Create a new filtering function that will add our where clause to the query
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
    // posts in the last 30 days
    $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')) . "'";
    return $where;
}

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );

$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'posts_per_page' => '5',
    'v_sortby' => 'views', 
    'post_type' => array( 'post', 'music', 'videos', 'albums' ),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'content',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'indy' ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )
    )
));
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    $the_query->the_post(); ?>


<a class="widget-post-title" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">
<?php the_title(); ?></a>

<a class="thumbnails-link" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"> </a>

<?php endwhile;

/* Restore original Post Data 
 * NB: Because we are using new WP_Query we aren't stomping on the 
 * original $wp_query and it does not need to be reset.
*/
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```